# Android elevation - same values different shadow

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, shadow, android-cardview, android-elevation

I encountered a strange error while setting elevations to items in recycler-view. I have two item types in adapter, first is a kind of dashboard with complex layout with three *cardview*s. Second one is classic item for data list where each item has *cardview* as root. each cardview in both layouts is defined as follows

First Item Type :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            app:cardElevation="3dp"
            >

        ....

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    ....

</LinearLayout>
```

Second Item Type:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="3dp"
        >

    ....

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

As you can see both *cardview*s have same elevation set but when i deploy this layout they have different shadows, any idea what could be the reason for this ?

I cut a part of screen and placed the cuts next to each other so you can see the problem ... 
[image]

**EDIT**

Layout for first item is pretty complex, but all three *cardview*s in this item type have same shadow (the one on the left in image above). Root cardview of second item type has the shadow that's on the right in the image.

```
default_elevation = 3dp 
default_corner_radius = 2dp
margins are 16dp, 8dp, 4dp etc ...
```

First item type :

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_and_half"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_padding"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_quarter"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_half"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_half"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_half"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/default_corner_radius"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/default_elevation"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/default_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/default_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_and_half"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_and_half"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="48sp"

                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="24sp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_padding"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_half"
                        android:textColor="@color/green"
                        />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_size"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_quarter"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_quarter"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_half"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_half"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_default"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_quarter"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/default_corner_radius"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/default_elevation">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_double"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_double"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/default_corner_radius"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/default_elevation">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_double"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_double"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_half"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_quarter"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Second item type :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_half"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_half"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_half"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/default_corner_radius"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/default_elevation"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/default_padding">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_quarter"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textAppearance="..(Too Long)"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

Comment: Any parent layout of cardview has elevation? Seems like the right one has more elevation in total.

Comment: nope, only parent of the cardview on right is <layout> tag

Comment: Could you post full layout xml? There is no way to understand without whole content.

Comment: sure, check out the edit I made

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same Problem, after some further investigation wanted to leave this here:

It seems to me, that the elevation is more focused on giving a feeling of depth than just "simply" casting a shadow. So, depending on where your view is located on the screen, the lighting is different and the shadow is casted differently, also the shadow is depending on the view's outline.

I recommend the following blog post in regard of this problem:
https://blog.usejournal.com/playing-with-elevation-in-android-91af4f3be596

Also very helpful is the elevation-tester-app mentioned in the blog post: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.seebrock3r.elevationtester&rdid=me.seebrock3r.elevationtester

But in conclusion I was not yet able to create an elevation based shadow which is consistent for every view regardless of on-screen-position :(