# Elevation increases with list position

Tags: android

I have a recyclerview with a CardView. Even if I dont specify the elevation explicitly, as the items get to the bottom of the screen, the elevation increases.  Haven't seen this behavior anywhere else, what can this be caused from?

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/card_layout"
    app:cardElevation="6dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/schedule_card_height"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/schedule_item_category"
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/background_eventlist_category"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                tools:text="Interview"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="1dp"
              android:background="@color/colorIcons"

              />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/schedule_item_actions"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
            android:padding="12dp">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/schedule_item_progress"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:visibility="gone"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/schedule_item_title"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top|center_vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/schedule_item_date"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/schedule_item.popup"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                tools:text="Awesome event because i say so"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/schedule_item_date"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                tools:text="25th April, 5PM (GMT)"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/schedule_item.popup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_dots"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: please display your xml layout file.

Comment: show ur xml code. try to put `useCompatPadding true` and set elevation to 1,2 or etc.

Comment: I just posted it

Comment: `app:cardElevation="6dp"` u said u didn't specify ?

Comment: yea i was just testing, it happens regardless of me putting it or not

Comment: so whats ur problem increasing elevation ? or just elevation ?

Comment: check the image, the elevation is different at bottom of list than at the top

Comment: hii try this one      android:maxCardElevation="6dp"

Comment: look https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nROYq8rpUMs&feature=youtu.be  here.. i thnk its a known issue..

Comment: @ND1010_ that property does not exist...

Comment: @SRBbans but no other app I've seen produces this issue

Comment: it might be a library update...  cardview or something ,, i hv no idea.. but you can see here.. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42608675/elevated-recyclerview-items-get-progressively-deformed-elevation-changes

and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001574/android-elevation-same-values-different-shadow

Comment: @MichelReap use app:cardMaxElevation="6dp"

Comment: @MichelReap please check my answer.

Comment: @ND1010_ that property does exist... no change though

Comment: okk now take LinearLayout parent to cardView

Comment: see my answer, i have not check it in my way but you should try this.....:)

Comment: I'm also having this issue, not sure if this behavior is intentional, did you find a solution @MichelReap ?

Answer (score 0):

The light is somewhere near the top of the device, tilted downward toward the display, so the lower the item is, the bigger the shadow distance.

Comment: i think.. he is using selfie flash light.. :D but the Logic is solid.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">  
      <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/card_layout"
            app:cardElevation="6dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/schedule_card_height"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/schedule_item_category"
                        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/background_eventlist_category"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        tools:text="Interview"/>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <View android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:layout_width="1dp"
                      android:background="@color/colorIcons"

                      />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/schedule_item_actions"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
                    android:padding="12dp">

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/schedule_item_progress"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:visibility="gone"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/schedule_item_title"
                        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="top|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/schedule_item_date"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/schedule_item.popup"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        tools:text="Awesome event because i say so"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/schedule_item_date"
                        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        tools:text="25th April, 5PM (GMT)"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/schedule_item.popup"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_dots"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is basically putting a LinearLayout wrapping the CardView right?